# Multiple pictures per product in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
product
-----------
product_id
product_name
product_description
price
size

productpictures
--------------
product_id
picture_id

pictures
---------
picture_id
picture_name
```

every product has 2 pictures but i only need the name, size, description and price once but i need both the pictures.

i used:

```
SELECT 
    product.product_description, 
    product.product_name, 
    product.price, 
    product.size,
    pictures.picture_name
FROM product
LEFT OUTER JOIN productpictures
    ON product.product_id = productpictures.product_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN bilde
    ON productpictures.picture_id = pictures.picture_id
WHERE product.product_id = 1
```

But I get two rows with double up name, price, size and description, but the picture names are different, but how can i insert both picture names into my php file so it shows the information about the product and both pictures?

i tried printing the row picture name but that only gave me the first name but not the second.

```
size     product_name      price   picture_name
50x70cm Sandvasket silke    399   Elfenben.PNG
50x70cm Sandvasket silke    399   SVElfenben.JPG
```

this is my current ressult with my current sql statement. basically whan i want in php is to echo the size name and price in a p tag, thats no problem but i also want to echo both the picture_names in a img tag

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Comment: Could you please provide sample data, your current result run by your query with that data, and your expected result?

Comment: you mean the data i entered into the tables? all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just exactly two pictures per product, one solution is to use *aggregation*:

```
SELECT 
    pr.product_description, 
    pr.product_name, 
    pr.price, 
    pr.size, 
    MAX(pi.picture_name) picture_name1, 
    MIN(pi.picture_name) picture_name2
FROM product pr
LEFT JOIN  productpictures pp ON pr.product_id = pp.product_id
LEFT JOIN pictures pi ON pp.picture_id = pi.picture_id
WHERE pr.product_id = 1
GROUP BY
    pr.product_id,
    pr.product_description, 
    pr.product_name, 
    pr.price, 
    pr.size
```

PS: I added table aliases to your query, they make the query easier to read and maintain (and allow self-`JOIN`ing when necessary...).

Comment: may i ask how shall i go forth in php with this? basically i want the info on the page and the two images there as well, The name of the product is "silk" and price is "299" and the images are "elfenben.jpg" and "lysgraa.jpg"

Comment: @AmmarMujezinovic: you can execute this query just like any other with PHP, using your favorite client (PDO, mysqli, ...). I am curious to know if this returns your expected output, are you able to run the query against your data and let me know?

Comment: Oh thank you @GMB it actually worked like a charm. you saved me hours of trial and error and researching and probably just giving up in the end

Comment: i have encountered a minor problem, it sorts the pictures by the alphabet so the one that is the last in the alphabet comes as picture_1, i want it to be sorted according the picture_id, so that the highest picture_id comes first. can i just use group by picture_id desc?

Comment: Could probably solve it by adding a c_ in front of every color so it gets stored by that